# Dynamic intent parameter for start activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create a method for starting activities. I don't want to write this every time:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Instead I want to use it like this: (Using 1 line instead of 2 lines)**

```
ShowActivity(LoginActivity);
```

**By using a custom method like this:**

```
public void ShowActivity(Activity act)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, act.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and maybe overloading further:

```
public void ShowActivity(Activity act, boolean finish)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, act.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    if(finish)
        CurrentActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Anyway, it's giving *cannot find symbol* error (I don't know why it's *cannot* instead of *can not* by the way). Is it possible to do so, if yes is it reasonable to do so? (Last one) If yes why not there is a 1-line method embedded to do this?

Do I think too much "C#ish" with this approach as a Java noob?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. *I'm an Java and Android noob such that I'm not even sure about the question's title. I don't know how to ask better, therefore I couldn't search properly if this question is duplicated or not. If it's so, apologies.*

Comment: Maybe another 1-line approach can be: `startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));` but it's still longer than my idea and not stopping me to repeat same code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

define a util class, like following:

```
public class AcitivtyUtil {
    public static void showActivity(Activity from, Class<?> to, boolean finish) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(from, to);
        from.startActivity(intent);
        if (finish) {
            from.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

then you can call `ActivityUtil.showActivity(this, TargetActivity.class, true|false)` at any Activity.

some error in your code:

```
public void ShowActivity(Activity act)  // here you can't pass a Activity object as parameter, you should pass Class<?>, so it should be act.class
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, act.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you don't want use util class, you can also define the `showActivity()` in your Activity class as member method, recommend define it in BaseActivity, so you need not duplicate it in all Activity.

```
public void showActivity(Class<?> to, boolean finish) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, to);
    startActivity(intent);
    if (finish) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to move first parameter(*this*) inside startActivity method and being able to call it as `ActivityUtil.startActivity(this, TargetActivity.class, true|false)` ?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk, sorry not very understand your question, could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong. `ActivityUtil.startActivity(TargetActivity.class, true|false)` Is it possible to not give *this* as parameter?

Comment: @ErtürkÖztürk I updated the answer, hope that can help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following:

```
public void ShowActivity(Activity act)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, act.getClass());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I edited my answer Ertürk.

Change the parameter of your Activity act parameter of your `showActivity` to Intent intent and pass the value of intent params to your method's intent.

So to use it, it'll be like:

```
showActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
```

Comment: But which activity is that? How I'm gonna call my LoginActivity this way? `<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_login"></activity>` ADDENDUM: sorry it seems you fixed, I'm gonna delete this comment

Comment: Are your sure you can `new TargetAcitivty()` in Android?? Acitivty is controlled by Android system, you can't and you shouldn't `new` a Acitivty!

Comment: i edited it. the new Activity i meant was your class like new LoginActivity() or new ProductsActivity() i edited the reply

Comment: you dont need to add any utils to achieve that. youre making things complicated

Comment: that also can't, you can't new any type Activity in Android, because the Activity has lifecycle, how it is created, destroy, all controlled by Android system.

Comment: of course you can. im doing a lot of it in my project. you can always instantiate new instance of your class

Comment: AFAIK you can instantiate Activity but you shouldn't in some scenarios like if you want to save its state and return where you took off later. `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` can be another reason you can't. ("C#ish" ideas)Educate me.